# Execute javascript function inside web-page from URL?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I save this code as: **C:/js.html**

Then I write in the address-bar of my browser:

**file:///C:/js.html#javascript:myFunction();**

But the Javascript function is not executed. Why?

How can I make this work?

Comment: You might consider using location.hash to dertmine a function to invoke.

Comment: This code is not supposed to execute the function until you click on the button

Comment: Also, add a header section, and put the script inside.

Comment: @fubbe Can you show me an example?

Comment: In comments below, you indicate you can't edit the webpage in question.  That's important to note, and requires a lot more detail about what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this short snipped. Visit your page with #test as location part of your url index.html#test.

```
function myHash() {
    alert('here iam!');
}

function hash() {
    var hash = location.hash;

    switch(hash) {
        case '#test' : myHash();
            break;
        default : break;
    }
}

hash();
```

Comment: add it to your script tag and take a look at @hello world's structure.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I need to call ANY javascript from ANY website in this way, not just from mine. Is this possible?

Comment: In short, nope. If you visit a page containing javascript, it will execute on pre defined purpose.

Comment: So is there absolutely no way to execute from the URL a javascript which is located or referenced inside the web-page? I mean, I don't even need to display the web-page, I only need to just execute the javascript.

Comment: This works only on page load (i.e. does not observe URL changes). Otherwise replace `hash()` with `window.onhashchange = hash();`

Comment: @CPH4 seems something triggered your suspicious handler :)

Comment: Isn't it possible to INJECT your hash code into the web-page from the URL?

Comment: Imagine this. Facevok.com/function(){deletemyuseraccount(); getdocumentbyid(yes-button).click} and then put it in url shortener bit.ly/notdangerous this is called xss. You dont want your site to be able to execute javascript from url. But there are ways to do it. But first you must join me to the dark side of the force.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your script tag between the head tags like so

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you asked for

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.hash)
eval(window.location.hash.substr(1))
</script>
```

Congratulation! You just caused an XSS vulnerability. Beware of site.html#deleteuseraccount()

Better way to do it but wrong answer to yourr question.

```
<script>
function() {
    if (location.hash === "#magicword") {
    YourMagicHere();
 }};
</script>
```